# Taylor expansion of likelihood function

Tags: statistics, taylor-expansion, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

$\require{\cancel}$

> ...For large samples, as a consequence of the central limit theorem, the
>   likelihood function approaches a gaussian, whose expected value is
>   equal to the maximum likelihood estimate. Indeed, expanding the
>   logarithm of the likelihood function around its maximum,
>
> $$\ln{\mathscr{L}(\theta)}=\ln{\mathscr{L}}(\hat\theta)-\dfrac{1}{2}\left|\dfrac{\partial^2\ln\mathscr{L}}{\partial
> {\theta}^2}\right|_\hat\theta\left(\theta-\hat\theta\right)^2 + \dots$$
>
> for a "sufficient large" number of samples, the so called parabolic
>   approximation can be considered, such that the likelihood function can
>   be approximated by a gaussian-like expression, i.e.,
>
> $$\mathscr{L}(\theta)\propto e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}\left|\dfrac{\partial^2\ln\mathscr{L}}{\partial {\theta}^2}\right|_\hat\theta(\theta-\hat\theta)^2}...$$

I tried the Taylor expansion at $ \hat\theta$ as:

$$\ln{\mathscr{L}(\theta)}=
\ln{\mathscr{L}}(\hat\theta)
+ \cancel{\left. \dfrac{\partial \ln\mathscr{L}}{\partial \theta}\right|_{\hat\theta}\left(\theta-\hat\theta\right)}
\color{red}+\dfrac{1}{2}\left. \dfrac{\partial^2\ln\mathscr{L}}{\partial
{\theta}^2}\right|_\hat\theta\left(\theta-\hat\theta\right)^2 
+ \dots$$

Why the minus sign?

Comment: Where does the quote come from by the way?

Comment: “Métodos Estatísticos em Física Experimental, Oguri V, 2014” (Portuguese)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minus sign comes from the fact that at the maximum of ln(L), the second order condition requires that necessarily ln(L)''<=0. And the opposite of the absolute value of ln(L)'' is equal in this case to ln(L)''.